# forget to move to another branch than master with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm using `Git` with a rails project.

Today i make a lot of changes and i forget to **move to** `another branch`,  so all these changes are in the master branch but **not committed yet**.

this is what i get when i do `git status` command :

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
#   modified:   app/models/user.rb
# .....

#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app/assets/javascripts/password_resets.js.coffee
#   app/assets/stylesheets/password_resets.css.scss
#   app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb
# .....
# ......
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

how i can solve this error and move all these untracked files from *master* **to another branch already exists** ? thank you.

Comment: Do `git checkout -b new_branch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If there are no commits marked C1, C2, etc. below

You're in the simple case; just use [Henrik N's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166881/1256452).

#### If there is a tracking branch

Your updated question/comments suggests that you have both committed changes and uncommitted changes, and you did them all on some tracking branch, such as `master` that tracks `origin/master` or `devel` that tracks `origin/devel`, but that you have not pushed any of them yet.  (I'll assume `master` but you can just change each `master` to the feature/development/whatever branch name below.)

As a diagram, your repo's commit tree and working directory/index now looks something like this:

```
M1 -...- M5 -- M6                    <-- origin/master
                 \
                  C1 -- C2           <-- master, HEAD=master
                          \
                           i, w      <-- "index" and working-tree files
```

Here `i` is the stuff in the index (`git add dir/file1`, `git rm file2`, etc), which `git status` shows as `changes to be committed`, and `w` is the stuff in your working directory that `git status` shows as `changes not staged for commit`.

Here's what you *want* it to look like:

```
M1 -...- M5 -- M6                    <-- master, origin/master
                 \
                  C1 -- C2           <-- my_branch, HEAD=my_branch
                          \
                           i, w      <-- "index" and working-tree files
```

Remember that branch labels are like sticky-notes ("yellow stickies" or "Post-It® notes" or whatever): they have a name written on them and are pasted on to a commit.  So what you have to do is add a new sticky-note, `my_branch`, pointing to commit C2, and also make `HEAD` refer to the new branch name:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

This uses the previous value of `HEAD` to name the commit that `my_branch` is pasted-on-to.  Since that commit is `C2` you now have both `master` and `my_branch` here.  It then rewrites `HEAD` to point to the name `my_branch`.  Now you have:

```
M1 -...- M5 -- M6                    <-- origin/master
                 \
                  C1 -- C2           <-- master, my_branch, HEAD=my_branch
                          \
                           i, w      <-- "index" and working-tree files
```

Now you need to move the sticky-note labeled `master` to point back where `origin/master` points.  There are two ways to do this, with `git reset`, or with `git branch`.  Using `git reset` is harder, so let's do it with `git branch`:

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

The `-f` (force) flag tells `git branch` to change an existing sticky-note, rather than failing because it exists, and `origin/master` gives which commit `master` should point-to: so git peels the label off `C2` and pastes it on `M6`, and you have the setup you wanted (the 2nd diagram).

---

Summary: it's just two commands:

```
git checkout -b my_branch           # create new branch and change HEAD
git branch -f master origin/master  # restore master to origin/master
```

You're now ready to check in changes as usual, on branch `my_branch`.  (`git add`, `git rm`, `git commit` as needed.)  That will add a new commit C3:

```
M1 -...- M5 -- M6                    <-- master, origin/master
                 \
                  C1 -- C2 -- C3     <-- my_branch, HEAD=my_branch
```

---

#### What if there is no tracking branch?

Well, that's OK, it's just a little harder.  Go back to the "have now" and "want" diagrams.  In these diagrams, the commit I labeled `M6` is the one you want `master` to name.  You now have to *find* M6.  Commits have these long hexadecimal-numeric (SHA-1) "true names" that never change, like 5e013711f5d6eb3f643ef562d49a131852aa4aa1 for example.  (`git rev-parse HEAD` will show the "true name" for the current, i.e., `HEAD`, commit.)  You can find that "true name", or you can find some alternate or abbreviated name that also names the same thing.

There are a whole lot of options for names, but let's stick with numbers that come out of `git log` and `git log --oneline`.  The latter gives you something like this:

```
97206f5 peerish: set socket options earlier
4881af5 add semtest.c
b3f8bea fdm: repair example
```

where the number is an abbreviated SHA-1 and the text is the first line of the commit message.  Since the logs are shown in reverse order, the top line is the most recent commit (`C2` in the example above), and then each next line is the next one back (well, it's more complicated with merges, but close enough).

Let's say that from the above, you can immediately tell that the commit I labeled `M6` is `b3f8bea`, i.e., that you need to skip two commits.  Simply supply that value as the last argument to `git branch`:

```
git branch -f master b3f8bea
```

If your repo is huge and old, or has a lot of merge commits, you might want your logs to include more "decoration".  I got these aliases from somewhere long ago:

```
[alias]
    lol = git log --graph --decorate --oneline
    lola = git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

so that I can run `git lol` and `git lola`.

Alternatively, if you know for sure there were exactly two commits, `master~2` (and in this case, after adding `my_branch`, `my_branch~2`) will get you the same SHA-1.  The `git rev-parse` command shows you exactly which SHA-1 any given name "means".  In one repo I have here, `HEAD~2` is the same as `origin/featureX`:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD~2
0f5a13497dd3da8aff8e452c8f56630f83253e79
$ git rev-parse origin/featureX
0f5a13497dd3da8aff8e452c8f56630f83253e79
```

but in general `git log` (or `git lol`, etc.) will get you the raw SHA-1 and you can add labels from there, as needed.

Comment: thank you fore details i understand 80% of what do you explain here but some things are difficult to understand :D thank you a lot for your answer. but the second command give me error: fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/master'

Comment: That indicates that you don't *have* an `origin/master`, i.e., there's no tracking branch that `master` used to track.  Is this purely a local repo?

Comment: perhaps i want to switch to master before execute the second command

Comment: BTW I checked your question-edit, is the problem more like: "have branch master, have branch devel, started working on code but was on branch master and the changes I made are meant for branch devel"?  If so, this is a (potentially) very different situation; it deserves a different StackOverflow question.

Comment: I solve problem adding new branch git checkout -b "new_branch" then git add . and git commit -m "my commit", finally i switch to master and i merge the change git merge new_branch. your answer is helpful and contains lot of informations so i think you are a git pro ^^ thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new branch and then commit, e.g.:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
git commit -am "My commit."
```

Comment: if i do this, i will not lose the changes I've made ?

Comment: You won't lose the changes.  You might feel more comfortable running `git branch my_branch` though, which will do the same thing, but does not invoke `checkout`. :-)  Note: if you *did* commit some changes on `master` already, that's also easy to correct/adjust, as long as you have not `push`ed them anywhere.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can i move these changes to an existing branch ? ( note : i update my question )

Comment: Oops, correction to my previous comment, `git branch my_branch` will create it but not change `HEAD`.  So use `git checkout -b`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create new branch.

Once you create a branch all the changes will be in the new branch.

and then clean your old stuff from master

```
// Checkout new branch
git checkout -b my_branch

// Prepare files for commit
git add .

// Commit changes
git commit -m "Your commit message"

// delete the dirty master
git branch -D master

// Now we are going to clean your changes from the master branch
// the -f is important in case you skipped the previous command to delete your master
git checkout -f master
```

Comment: i think if i delete master branch in the last to clean changes , i will also lose the old merged branchs